# ¿Cómo manipular un SVG externo con CSS?

Tags: css, svg

HTML usado para mostrar los iconos SVG:

```
<div>
    <div class="social-bar">

        <ul class="icon-facebook" target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/" title="Facebook">
             <img src="../../assets/img/icon-facebook.svg" class="icon-facebook" alt="Icon Facebook">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS utilizado, los intenté editar pero no paso nada:

```
svg.icon-facebook,
.icon-instagram,
.icon-twitter,
.icon-reddit {
    fill: #ffffff !important;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.icon-facebook:hover,
.icon-instagram:hover,
.icon-twitter:hover,
.icon-reddit:hover {
    fill: whitesmoke !important;
}
```

He intentado con este código pero no me da, incluso lo intenté hasta con el `id`. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

---

Y este es la definición del icono **SVG**:

```
<svg
    aria-hidden="true"
    focusable="false"
    data-prefix="fab"
    data-icon="facebook"
    class="icon-facebook"
    role="img"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 320 512">

    <path
        fill="currentColor"
        d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Si quieres acceder a las propiedades de un `svg` tendrás que poner el `svg` como código en el html, si lo pones como un recurso de la etiqueta `img` como lo tienes ahora no podrás hacerlo.

Comment: Una opción sería utilizar un filtro css. Por ejemplo si el elemento svg no tiene fill o tiene fill="black" para cambiarlo a blanco puedes utilizar `filter:invert(1)` para la imagen. Para un blanco roto (en hover) puedes utilizar  `filter:invert(.7)` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Hay una manera más conveniente de mostrar svg en tu website que te permitirá manipularlo con css, colores, tamaños, etc.

Usando la dirección absoluta del recurso:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="https://tudominio.org/images/tusvg.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

También puedes usar rutas relativas como `/images/tusvg.svg` o `../cualquier/path/tusvg.svg`

Esta etiqueta `<use xlink:href>` será reemplazada por el código xml del svg cuando sea renderizada en tu sitio web, esto te permitirá manipular los estilos de los elementos del svg definiendo estilos css en tu sitio web.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que estás usando el parámetro `fill="currentColor"`.

Si miramos la documentación del estándar SVG en el apartado de [parámetros de pintado](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) (aquellos valores que pueden indicarse en atributos `fill`, `stroke`, etc) podremos leer lo siguiente:

> **currentColor**: Indicates that painting shall be done using the color specified by the current animated value of the `color` property. This mechanism is provided to facilitate sharing of color attributes between parent grammars such as other (non-SVG) XML. This mechanism allows you to define a style in your HTML which sets the `color` property and then pass that style to the SVG user agent so that your SVG text will draw in the same color.

Que en castellano es:

> **currentColor**: indica que el pintado se realizará utilizando el color especificado por el valor animado actual de la propiedad `color`. Este mecanismo se proporciona para facilitar el intercambio de atributos de color entre documentos padre, como otros XML (no SVG). Este mecanismo te permite definir un estilo en tu HTML que establece la propiedad `color` y luego pasar ese estilo al agente de usuario SVG para que tu texto SVG se dibuje en el mismo color.

Es decir, sirve para que tu logotipo se dibuje **con el mismo color del texto que lo rodea**.

Entonces, el atributo CSS que necesitas cambiar no es `fill`, es `color`:

```
.icon-facebook {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.icon-facebook:hover {
  color: whitesmoke !important;
}
```

Una vez realizado el cambio podrás ver reflejado los cambios en el SVG siempre que sea agregado al documento como SVG en línea o externo:

```
<h3>SVG externo</h3>
<p><svg class="icon-facebook"><use xlink:href="icon-facebook.svg#facebook"></use></svg></p>
<h3>SVG en línea</h3>
<p><svg class="icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" id="facebook"><path fill="currentColor"
  d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"></path></svg></p>
```

Ejemplo:

```css
.icon-facebook {
  color: blue !important;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.icon-facebook:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<h3>SVG en línea (pasa el ratón por encima)</h3>
<p><svg class="icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" id="facebook"><path fill="currentColor"
  d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"></path></svg></p>
```

Sin embargo no podrás obtener el mismo resultado si lo insertas como objeto (`<object>`) o imagen (`svg`) tal y como puedes ver en el repositorio github (https://github.com/ojgarciab/299519-stackoverflow-es) que te he preparado para que puedas probar el funcionamiento en línea:

[image: Gitpod Ready-to-Code]

Answer (score 0):

No se puede modificar por CSS un SVG cargado externamente en un tag `<img>`, sin embargo existen varias opciones para conseguir lo que buscas.

Una opción sería como te indicaban en algún comantario embeber el SVG en el HTML, aunque embeber el contenido del icono no siempre es lo deseado si se quiere reutiliar en varios sitios por ejemplo.

La solución que te propongo es utilizar una fuente (TTF, webf, eof, ...) para contener los iconos, la única limitación es que deben ser monocromáticos o de 2 tonos como máximos, si no se complica un poco.

Por ejemplo fontawesome tiene una fuente con iconos de marcas y se incluye Facebook, puedes ver un ejemplo en el siguiente enlace: https://jsfiddle.net/nbL2u3sr/1/

En resumen sería importar los CSS de Fontawesome:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/brands.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
```

El código HTML con el icono quedaría similar a esto:

```
<div>    
    <div class="social-bar">

        <ul class="icon-facebook" target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/" title="Facebook">
             <i class="myicon fab fa-facebook"></i>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el CSS para adaptar el icono algo como:

```
.myicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
}
```

Por último, si no quieres cargar una fuente con tantos iconos y lo que quieres es cargar únicamente algunos que además pueden no ser públicos como facebook, es decir, iconos SVG personalizados, entonces puedes usar una herramienta online para generar tu propia fuente TTF a partir de tus iconos en SVG, puedes usar por ejemplo: http://fontello.com/ o https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un `id` a la parte de tu *SVG* que deseas modificar para luego poderte referir él.

Código *JavaScript*:

```
var selectorId=document.getElementById( TU ID)
selectorId.setAttributeNS(null, "TU PROPIEDAD A MODIFICAR ", VALOR)
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la pregunta no es sobre _JavaScript_, si no que es sobre _CSS_. Yo eliminariía la respuesta.

Comment: Este código no funciona con SVG cargados como imagen, ni como objeto ni como SVG externo, sólo con un SVG en línea. Además, como dice @ArtEze, la pregunta indica explícitamente que desea hacerlo usando CSS, no Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que encontré es que se puede usar la etiqueta `<object>`

```
<object data="vector.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Y también es necesario agregar:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
```

al inicio del SVG.

Es compatible en la mayoría de navegadores, pero en caso de no serlo o que exista algún error se puede poner una alternativa dentro de la etiqueta

```
<object data="vector.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <img src="vector.png">
</object>
```

PD: En caso que no se muestre el SVG prueba cambiando sus dimensiones.

> https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/