# ¿Se puede insertar un SVG en HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

Sé que se puede agregar con una etiqueta `<img>`, por ejemplo:

```
<img src="vector.svg">
```

También que puedes agregar directamente el SVG:

```
<svg class="vector"> ... </svg>
```

Éste método es mejor porque puedes editar propiedades del SVG en CSS, por ejemplo:

```
.vector {fill: white}
```

Pero el problema es que tienes que pegar **todo** el SVG en el documento HTML

¿Existe alguna forma de añadir un SVG como un archivo externo pero que, a su vez, me permita modificar sus propiedades desde CSS?

Comment: ¿Lista de propiedades que quieres modificar?

Comment: El `fill` en cada path del SVG

Comment: La otra pregunta no tiene respuesta aceptada, todas las respuestas tienen una puntuación de 0 menos una que tiene 2. Además, en ésta se da una solución real mientras que en la otra se hace uso de una hoja de estilos externa al documento (y estática). Voto la reapertura.

Comment: Por favor, ahora que [he dado respuesta a la otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336436/18608), podréis comprobar que **no tienen absolutamente nada que ver una con otra**. Por favor, votad la reapertura. Gracias.

Comment: Ok, perfecto. No, gracias a tí.

Comment: Tras lo hablado creo que tienes razón, he votado la reapertura, solo falta 1 voto para que se reabra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque puedes hacer uso de [`<use xlink:href="...#id">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href#use) de la siguiente manera:

```
<svg class="vector">
   <use xlink:href="vector.svg#su_id"></use>
</svg>
```

Tendrás el problema de tener el DOM del `<svg>` oculto, por lo que sólo podrás cambiar propiedades que se hereden a lo largo de todos los elementos que lo componen. Es decir, sólo puedes cambiar el estilo `fill`, por ejemplo, de todos los `<path>` sin poder separarlos entre sí.

Sin embargo, puedes hacer uso del siguiente código javascript para realizar la carga del SVG dentro del DOM del documento.

Para ello primero deberemos preparar los `<svg>` con los datos necesarios:

```
<svg data-src="Heart.svg"></svg>
```

Y posteriormente, en javascript, deberemos realizar la carga del SVG usando, por ejemplo, [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch):

```
/* Cargamos los svg tras la carga del DOM */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  /* Buscamos cada elemento svg con el atributo "src" */
  document.querySelectorAll('svg[data-src]').forEach(svg => {
    /* Cargamos el contenido en su HTML interno */
    fetch(svg.dataset.src)
      .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
      .then(xml => svg.innerHTML = xml);
  });
});
```

De esta manera podrás controlar el contenido con más detalle ya que forma parte del DOM del documento.

Te he preparado un [repositorio github con el código](https://github.com/ojgarciab/335841-stackoverflow-es) y un [gitpod para probarlo en línea](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/335841-stackoverflow-es):

[image: Gitpod Ready-to-Code]

En él podrás ver que en los `<svg>` que usan `<use xlink:href>` no se puede "llegar" a los elementos `<path>` en la hoja de estilos, sin embargo los cargados en el DOM por javascript sí (se verán de color diferente).

Answer (score 0):

**Se pueden incluir una SVG como `img`** por ejemplo:

```
<img src="./static/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo">
```

Esto permite modificar mediantes CSS las propiedades que se pueden controlar para cualquier otra imagen: tamaño, posición, rotación, bordes, ...

Como en el caso anterior, **puedes usar el SVG como imagen de fondo**. Tendras el mismo tipo de limitaciones en su manipulación: no puedes cambiar sus propiedades internas.

La otra forma de **incluir un SVG, y poder controlar las propiedades "internas"**, es incluir esta en línea en el documento HTML, así podras cambiar, por ejemplo, su color. Un primer paso sería optimizar / minificar el SVG, con herramientas como:

https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser, https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ o usando Node: https://github.com/svg/svgo

Seguidamente incluirla en el HTML, dentro de las etiquetas `svg`, *donde se pueden aplicar directamente estilos, filtros, etc.*:

```
<svg>
    <path class="logo" ...></path>
</svg>
```

e indicar los cambios en el CSS:

```
.logo {
    fill: green;
}
```

Más detalles en este artículo: [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)